# Web User Control get parent control ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, ascx

**ASCX**

```
<dx:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="ASPxGridViewExporter1" runat="server">
</dx:ASPxGridViewExporter>

<dx:ASPxButton ID="buttonSaveAs" runat="server" ToolTip="Export and save" Style="vertical-align: middle;"
                OnClick="buttonSaveAs_Click" Text="Save" Width="51px" />
```

**ASPX that include above ASCX**

```
<div>
    //ASCX
</div>
<div>
    <dx:ASPxPivotGrid ID="ASPxPivotGridElectricMeterReadings" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceElectricMeterReadings" EnableCallBacks="False" Width="1000px">
    </dx:ASPxPivotGrid>
</div>
```

**ASCX.cs**

```
protected void buttonSaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I want to get pivotGridId from ASPX
    ASPxGridViewExporter1.ASPxPivotGridID = ASPX-PivotGrid-ID
}
```

How can I pass ASPX control ID to ASCX button_click_event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a property to your ascx code behind and populate it in the aspx initialize event.

**ASCX.cs**

```
public string PivotGridID { get; set; }
```

**ASPX.cs**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    exportPivotGrid.PivotGridID = ASPxPivotGridElectricMeterReadings.ID;
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's in VB.Net but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try, declaration of the parent control, in page load event(User Control) and must be outside the postback event.

```
 (this.Parent.Parent).FindControl("ErrLabel") as Label;
```